# How to disable density setting?

Tags: java, android, xml

In Android N, there is a new feature that allows the user to change display size or the screen density (Located in the display settings area).

Putting aside the actual screen sizes themselves, is there a way to disable or ignore this setting?

The reason I'm asking is because this setting messes up UI and makes everything look too squished or on smaller tablets(600dp) launch the phone version of the app.

I've tested my app on almost two dozen emulators and had no problems in the past till now.

Comment: "this setting messes up UI" -- please your UI. Your users are changing that setting for *their* benefit, and so you should honor their request. Moreover, there may be actual hardware that has similar characteristics and will cause similar problems for your UI.

Comment: It's not that simple, I have ALOT of controls on a few of my pages(Activity/Fragments) and I'm not going to have time to redesign them to fit all the controls and test them all myself to make sure this doesn't happen till much later. I completely understand what your saying, but it's not possible at this time.(Other projects going on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would generally agree with CommonsWare that need for this implementation is generally pointing to the poorly designed Layout, you could override default screen density with following code:

```
    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.fontScale = 1f; 
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    configuration.densityDpi = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

Comment: For all those taking this approach, make sure you put early in in the code like after setting the content view. Otherwise the layout will probably look messed up from a different perspective than initially before putting this code in.

Comment: However it doesn't fix the other half of the problem; smaller tablets launching phone apps